# Online Retoure from DHL

Tags: dhl

I would like to know how I can implement a DHL Retourenportal in my Magento Store per iFrame.

I mean, I would like to integrate a booking form for returns direct in my shop. So that the customers can print out the return label directly on my website.

Answer (score 1):

Create a CMS page with the name and identifier you want and add the iFrame inside it. It will  cover your needs if it is only an iframe.